# Updating Cell Height after Fetching an Image from the Database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to update the height of my tableview cell after loading an image from the database asynchronously.
The use case is:
Fetch the image when the cell is visible. So i have to call `loadImageWith(callBack: () -> ()) in the cell it self.
When i receive the callBack, i would like to update the particular cell with the image.
For the image there is no placeholder etc. So if no image is available the cell is empty.

I have tried to call 
`self.tableView.beginUpdates()
 self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()`
in the callBack like described in other threads but obviously this leads to an infinite loop.
I also tried to call `cell.needsLayout` or/and `cell.layoutIfNeeded` after adding the image to the image view.
with no effect on the row.

I'm not using any third party library, because i need to fetch the image data from the local database not from a server.

If im loading all the images in viewDidLoad and call
 `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)`

 then it works but the requirement is to load just the visible cells.

Hope any has a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the height of cell after image uploaded as

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
 self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) 
selectedCell.height = yourHeight
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```